How to use/keep custom setter method with MyBatis?
MyBatis generates the following code in one of my entity classes:
    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator. This field corresponds to the database column
     * my_field
     *
     * @mbg.generated {DATETIME}
     */
    @ParentToChildSync(sync = StringSync.class)
    protected String myField;

I need to log the value of "myField". But as it is used widely in my project, the best place to log it would be in the setter I think.
So I would like to write a custom setter to be able to add a log entry like so:
    // ...
    @ParentToChildSync(sync = StringSync.class)
    protected String myField;

    protected void setMyField(String myField) {
        this.myField = myField;
        log.add('set my field as: %s', myField);
    }

Is this how I should do it?
And if so how do I prevent MyBatis from overwriting/removing this customer setter next time I run the MyBatis generation?
Thank you!

Pretty much, yes. MyBatis-Generator only overwrites methods with @mbg.generated annotation.

Oh I see. Let me try this. Thank you. Could you write it as an answer so I can check it if it works?

I forgot to mention the Java file merge is supported only in MBG Eclipse plugin currently. Please see the doc.
